# Best way to serve different sized ad units on different URLs through DFP?

Tags: javascript, css, ads, google-dfp, dynamic-data-display

I'm using custom keys in DFP to segment my website based on category. For some of these categories, I'd like to serve a 300x600 ad unit in the right-hand sidebar. For others, I'd like to stick with the 300x250 unit. (I'm assuming that when I serve the 300x600 unit, it'll push other elements in said sidebar downwards, which is fine.)

My thought process for achieving this is:
1) Create a 300x600 ad tag in DFP
2) Place this ad tag in site code within the appropriate  in the sidebar
3) ?

...so, I'm not sure where this new tag needs to be placed and (equally important) how to prioritize the 300x600s to essentially serve ahead of what are typically run-of-site campaigns to the 300x250 units.

Let me know if I can provide any more info, not sure how clear this is.

Thanks to everyone in advance,
J